# optimising my adding prefixing zeros function

Tags: c#, function

Below is my function, as you can see I want to prefix the quote no with leading zeros, this if statement ive made doesnt seem like the best way, i was wondering if anyone had a better way of doing this, im sure there will be.

Thanks alot

```
        int QuoteNo = currQuotetNo + 1;
        string strQuoteNo = "";
        if (QuoteNo.ToString().Length > 1)
        {
            strQuoteNo = "0000" + QuoteNo.ToString();
        }
        else if (QuoteNo.ToString().Length > 2)
        {
            strQuoteNo = "000" + QuoteNo.ToString();
        }
        else if (QuoteNo.ToString().Length > 3)
        {
            strQuoteNo = "00" + QuoteNo.ToString();
        }
        else if (QuoteNo.ToString().Length > 4)
        {
            strQuoteNo = "00" + QuoteNo.ToString();
        }
        else if (QuoteNo.ToString().Length > 5)
        {
            strQuoteNo = "0" + QuoteNo.ToString();
        }
        else if (QuoteNo.ToString().Length > 6)
        {
            strQuoteNo =  QuoteNo.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            strQuoteNo = QuoteNo.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: I think it worth asking such questions on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Addition to the answers: In the case that you need multiple `if`, try use `switch`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are trying to pad you string with zeros try using ToString.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx

Ref:

> You can pad an integer with leading zeros by using the "D" standard
>   numeric format string together with a precision specifier. You can pad
>   both integer and floating-point numbers with leading zeros by using a
>   custom numeric format string.

Code:

```
int QuoteNo = currQuotetNo + 1;
string strQuoteNo = QuoteNo.ToString("D4");
```

Answer (score 7):

First, I can't see that this works - surely anything that's > 1 will get caught by the first one?  So none of the other `else if`'s would ever be reached.

Second, I think you want to look at number formatting.  This should work:

`QuoteNo.ToString("000000");`

Comment: ah yes i need to use = instead of > i only want to prepend with the correct ammount of zeros, will to string "00000" do it? THanks

Comment: `ToString("000000")` would always return a string that's 6 characters.  Try it!

Answer (score 2):

```
string strQuoteNo = QuoteNo.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0');
```